# Cannot save Irish characters into database Symfony1.2

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, propel

What I need

- i need to store irish characters in oracle database.

Json data

```
{
  surname: "jéíóú",
  forename: "jéíóú",
}
```

database.yml  (orm used propel)

```
  dev:
propel:
param:
  classname:  DebugPDO
  host:       ''
  dsn:        'oci:dbname='
  username:   **
  password:   **
sessions_db:
class:        sfPDODatabase
param:
  classname:  DoctrinePDO
  dsn:        'oci:dbname='
  username:   **
  password:   **
  encoding:   utf8
  charset: UTF8
  persistent: false
  pooling:    false
```

- i have reffered url http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#setup-utf-8

> input
>   enetered data - jéíóú
>
> Output
>   seems to become : jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº
>
> But i need Output to be
>    jéíóú

- i have an idea about oracle how it does

  ```
  by doing ascii( like a  by some ascii code) through this i can insert into oracle.
  ```
- but i need help in propel orm and symfony.
- by doing googling i found symfony does utf8 by default in all column.
- but i need to insert same string into database.
- any suggestion is most welcome.

can any one explain why its get's happen

> input  jéíóú then pass paramater from api to oracle proc
>
> output while accessing value in procedure value get changed to  jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº
>
> oracle also escaping special char

sql

```
         select convert('jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº','us7ascii','utf8') from dual;
```

Comment: What have you done on the oracle side to make utf8 work?

Comment: or by doing select ascii('©') from dual

Comment: update tb set forename='jéíóú' where item_seq='2567'  //output jéíóú same ie oracle handles it.

Comment: Right, but have you configured oracle in any way to be able to handle utf8?

Comment: as im using utf8 in database.yml http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_3/en/07-Databases

Comment: i tried to comment/uncomment utf in charset but still the same resutl any help please.

Comment: Right, you have mentioned few times here and in the question that you use utf8 in your code. But have you configured oracle to deal with utf8?

Comment: as i think symfony may have some bug

Comment: Why do you think so? Have you configured oracle to deal with utf8?

Comment: i did thi sql select convert('jÃ©Ã­Ã³Ãº','us7ascii','utf8') from dual;

Comment: Please use tag Symfony1. Symfony  = Symfony 2.0 and up.